# Python - Summation of a function implementation

Tags: python, function, numpy, sum

How can I implement the following function in python using numpy:

[image]

Where:

- X is a numpy matrix (500 * 500)
- X` is another numpy matrix (500 * 500)
- Wi is a weight vector of dimensionality equal to the dimensionality of X, with each entry in Wi drawn independently from [image]
- n could be any large value

The values of X and X` are read from a csv file I have. I tried the following but it is not getting me any result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

data = np.loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',')

x = data[:,:500]
x_hat = data[:,501:1001]

n = 400
w = np.random.uniform(0,1,500)
Kapprox = (1/n)*np.sum( max(0,w*x)*max(0,w*x_hat),n)

plt.plot(Kapprox)
```

Comment: if `wi` is a scalar, then `wi*x` is still a matrix, so, what does the maximum between 0 and a matrix mean?

Comment: I updated the post, please see bullet item 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should work:

`Kapprox = (1/n)*np.sum([max(0, np.matmul(wi, x).max())*max(0, np.matmul(wi, x_hat).max()) for wi in your_w])`

Comment: how is this considering the summation from i=1 to n ?

Comment: I tried the above and got the following: ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

Comment: I used list comprehension, I'm doing the operation for each `wi` in `your_w` that will be the list with all `wi`.

Comment: The error is because your are using matrices of wrong dimension.

Comment: I substituted your_w with np.random.uniform(0,1,500)

Comment: You can't, `wi` can't be a scalar. It must be a vector 1x500 as your matrix `x` is 500x500.

Comment: so what should I use for Wi to be drawn independently from N(0,1)?

Comment: what is N(0,1)?

Comment: I used Kapprox = (1/n)*np.sum([max(0, np.matmul(wi, x).max())*max(0, np.matmul(wi, x_hat).max()) for wi in np.random.uniform(0,1,(1,500))]) and I got the value as zero for Kapprox

Comment: What you mean by 'drawn independently from normal distribution'?

Comment: I executed it and I got Kapprox = 0.0

Comment: I don't know the meaning of your formula so I can't tell you if the result it's correct.

Comment: I saw an error. With `np.random.uniform(0,1,(1,500))` you are creating just one vector, while you need `n` vectors.

Comment: Thanks Fedrico I will try to change its size.